# What is a regular expression to validate only work emails in JS (declining free email services such as Gmail)?

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, email

What is a regular expression to validate only work email addresses in JavaScript (declining free email services such as Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook.)?

I have written the pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+.[a-z]{2,3}$/; to validate free email addresses but I don't know how to validate only work emails

Here's my code:

```
// validate email address
var email = document.getElementById('email');

function validateEmail() {
  var emailValue = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (emailValue.match(pattern)) {
    email.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  } else {
    email.classList.add("is-invalid");
  }
}

email.addEventListener('keydown', validateEmail);
```

Comment: Before or after validation for the correct email address you can user JavaScripts built-in function like ``search()`` and search for like **@gmail** or **@yahoo** or any other you want to detect.

Comment: The best way to validate an email address is to send an email and check the return value. 
Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can validate that email is either **correct** or **not**. 
Your logic for validation will be handling that validation.

> emailValue.match(pattern)

Now if email **pass** the **validation** then use JavaScript's built-in function `search()` you search for free service email that you wish for.

If email has free email serive then you can **reject** that email.

Check below code which you can tweak around for your use case.

```js
let email1 = "emailfortest@gmail.com";
let email2 = "emailfortest@mycompany.com";
let email3 = "emailfortest@yahoo.com";

function validateEmail(emailAddress) {
  const pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  const notExceptedEmail = ['@gmail', '@yahoo'];
  let isFreeServiceEmailFlag = false;
  if (emailAddress.match(pattern)) {
    for(let i = 0; i < notExceptedEmail.length; i++){
       if(emailAddress.search(`${notExceptedEmail[i]}`) > -1){
         isFreeServiceEmailFlag = true;
       }
    }
    
    if(isFreeServiceEmailFlag == true)
      console.log('Cannot user free email service account');
    else
      console.log('Valid Email');
  } 
  else 
    console.log('Invalid Email');
}

validateEmail(email1);
validateEmail(email2);
validateEmail(email3);
```

Comment: Two or three character for TLD is really short. See [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Comment: I have found this regex that will only validate work email addresses: 
/^[^ ]+@[me|mac|icloud|gmail|googlemail|hotmail|live|msn|outlook|yahoo|ymail|aol]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/